# Morphing curves with ImagePeriodogram

Tags: graphics, image-processing, fourier-analysis

Any idea how to achieve smooth transition from one image to another (so that the curves are morphing from one shape to another)?

I am aware that `ImagePeriodogram` uses discrete Fourier transform and also `DiskMatrix` produce only discrete outputs but slight change in `DiskMatrix` should produce slight change in `ImagePeriodogram`. The problem is that I can not achieve this slight change in `DiskMatrix`.

```
Manipulate[ImagePeriodogram[Image[DiskMatrix[i,1000],ImageSize->200]],{i,1,20}]
```

[image] [image]

Image produces using @ydd code - The problem is that the speed of morphing is not constant but changes with like a sine function.

[image]

Comment: As you noted, `DiskMatrix` does not change continuously with its first argument. I suppose you could do a spline interpolation of the `DiskMatrix` for different radii, but you'd have to be very careful to make sure the interpolation isn't doing anything wild, especially between points that don't change:

$$ $$
`dmList = {#, DiskMatrix[#, 1000]} & /@ Range[1, 20, 0.1];`
`dmInt = Interpolation[dmList, Method -> "Spline"]`

$$ $$
Maybe  you should just leave it as is though, because the reason it's not changing is because the `DiskMatrix` is inherently discrete as a function of radius

Comment: I used your code... see image I produced... morphing is not of constant speed.

Comment: To make the animation smoother would removing from `dmList` the elements where there was no change help?  And/or set the number of interpolations between elements to be proportional to some measure of difference between two successive elements?  For example, using the standard deviation:  `sd = Table[{i, StandardDeviation[Flatten[dmList[[i - 1, 2]] - dmList[[i, 2]]]]}, {i, 2, Length[dmList[[All, 2]]]}];`.  Also, would you include the full code where you used @ydd 's suggestion?

Comment: `dmList={#,DiskMatrix[#,1000]}&/@Range[1,20,1];dmInt=Interpolation[dmList,Method->"Spline"];Manipulate[ImagePeriodogram@Image[dmInt[i],ImageSize->200],{i,0,10,0.01}]`